# Leaflet inbuild AJAX methods for WMTS getCapabilities request

Tags: javascript, leaflet, ajax

I was wondering whether the Leaflet library has inbuilt methods to make AJAX requests. My goal is to create a plugin that makes an XMLHttpRequest request to a specified WMTS resource and parse the XML response to JSON notation. If the library does not integrate AJAX methods I would use vanilla JS to require the the information.